# Kotlin KMM stop coroutine flow with infinite loop properly

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kmm

I'm building a KMM app for retrieving news.
My app fetches news every 30 seconds and save it in a local database. User must be logged for use it. When user want to logout i need to stop refreshing news and delete the local database.
How do i stop a flow with an infinite loop properly without use static variabile?

I designed the app like follows:

- ViewModel (separate for Android and iOS)
- UseCase (shared)
- Repository (shared)
- Data source (shared)
- Android Jetpack compose single activity
- iOS SwiftUI

Android ViewModel:(iOS use ObservableObject, but logic is the same)

```
@HiltViewModel
class NewsViewModel @Inject constructor(
   private val startFetchingNews: GetNewsUseCase,
   private val stopFetchingNews: StopGettingNewsUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {
   private val _mutableNewsUiState = MutableStateFlow(NewsState())
   val newsUiState: StateFlow<NewsState> get() = _mutableNewsUiState.asStateFlow()

   fun onTriggerEvent(action: MapEvents) {
       when (action) {
           is NewsEvent.GetNews -> {
            getNews()
          }
           is MapEvents.StopNews -> {
            //????
           }
           else -> {

           }
       }
   }

   private fun getNews()() {
       startFetchingNews().collectCommon(viewModelScope) { result ->
           when {
               result.error -> {
                //update state
               }
               result.succeeded -> {
                //update state
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

UseCase:

```
class GetNewsUseCase(
   private val newsRepo: NewsRepoInterface) {
   companion object {
       private val UPDATE_INTERVAL = 30.seconds
   }

   operator fun invoke(): CommonFlow<Result<List<News>>> = flow {
       while (true) {
           emit(Result.loading())
           val result = newsRepo.getNews()

           if (result.succeeded) {
               // emit result
           } else {
               //emit error
           }

           delay(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
       }
   }.asCommonFlow()
}
```

Repository:

```
class NewsRepository(
   private val sourceNews: SourceNews,
   private val cacheNews: CacheNews) : NewsRepoInterface {

   override suspend fun getNews(): Result<List<News>> {
    
       val news = sourceNews.fetchNews()

          //.....

       cacheNews.insert(news) //could be a lot of news

       return Result.data(cacheNews.selectAll())
   }
}
```

Flow extension functions:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.asCommonFlow(): CommonFlow<T> = CommonFlow(this)

class CommonFlow<T>(private val origin: Flow<T>) : Flow<T> by origin {
fun collectCommon(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null, // 'viewModelScope' on Android and 'nil' on iOS
    callback: (T) -> Unit, // callback on each emission
) {
    onEach {
        callback(it)
    }.launchIn(coroutineScope ?: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main))
}
}
```

I tried to move the *while* loop inside repository, so maybe i can break the loop with a singleton repository, but then i must change the *getNews* method to flow and collect inside GetNewsUseCase (so a flow inside another flow).
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `launchIn` on a Flow, it returns a Job. Hang on to a reference to this Job in a property, and you can call `cancel()` on it when you want to stop collecting it.

I don't see the point of the CommonFlow class. You could simply write `collectCommon` as an extension function of `Flow` directly.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectCommon(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null, // 'viewModelScope' on Android and 'nil' on iOS
    callback: (T) -> Unit, // callback on each emission
): Job {
    return onEach {
        callback(it)
    }.launchIn(coroutineScope ?: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main))
}

// ...

   private var fetchNewsJob: Job? = null

   private fun getNews()() {
       fetchNewsJob = startFetchingNews().collectCommon(viewModelScope) { result ->
           when {
               result.error -> {
                //update state
               }
               result.succeeded -> {
                //update state
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

In my opinion, `collectCommon` should be eliminated entirely because all it does is obfuscate your code a little bit. It saves only one line of code at the expense of clarity. It's kind of an antipattern to create a CoroutineScope whose reference you do not keep so you can manage the coroutines running in it--might as well use GlobalScope instead to be clear you don't intend to manage the scope lifecycle so it becomes clear you *must* manually cancel the Job, not just in the case of the news source change, but also when the UI it's associated with goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for answering! For Android `CoroutineScope` used is `viewModelScope` and the lifecycle is managed by Android `ViewModel`. Since i have 2 separate viewmodels, 1 for Android in Kotlin and 1 for iOS in Swift, apart from section of the  while loop, it should be fine i suppose. Extension functions are not supported in Swift using KMM plugin (iOS `ViewModel`), so it must be a class for now.